# Workout change operation with temporal table records

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016, temporal-tables

I have just started using using temporal tables/system versioning, its very easy to setup and get going in terms of querying the data. The one thing missing for me is storing the change operation (update/insert/delete) or generating it on the fly from the system_time period. Can anyone point me in the right direction to achieve this? Or isn't this achievable?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, since the article got published recently -- are you looking for something like this? http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2017/02/14/solving-the-net-changes-problem-with-temporal-tables-t-sql-tuesday-087.aspx

Comment: Also see https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3682/sql-server-2016-tsql-syntax-to-query-temporal-tables/

Comment: Note, temporal isn't really an *auditing* solution - it is meant to give you an accurate view of what a row looked at a point in time or during a time frame.  It can show you all the versions of the rows but it doesn't really give any more insight into the DML activity that did that...

Comment: @AaronBertrand thats what i was thinking also, i kind of wanted a bit of the CDC functionality, but wondered if there was anything i could do with temporal table data as its so clean and easy to get going. Regarding the article above i had a go but the results i was getting matching up.